# Jest - afterEach() - method call with and without parenthesis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

This is most likely a basic Javascript question, but the context I am asking it in is a test using https://jestjs.io/ as that is where I encountered it.

The following jest test code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {cleanup} from 'react-testing-library';
import 'jest-dom/extend-expect';

afterEach(cleanup());

test("Hello World", () => {});
// several other tests but they they are not relevant to this example and have been excluded to keep the question simple
```

results in the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

    at resolve (/tmp/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:38:11)
    at Promise (<anonymous>)
    at mapper (/tmp/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:31:21)
    at Promise.resolve.then.el (/tmp/node_modules/p-map/index.js:46:16)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Everything works as expected if I remove the parenthesis after cleanup

```
afterEach(cleanup);
```

After a bit of reading, I understood that this was happening as I was not appreciating the difference between a method call vs a method reference.

However, my question is - **why is the error message/trace so cryptic?** How does one get to the root cause by looking at the error message/trace? I had to remove 1 line at a time from my test to figure out the offensive line throwing the error. Is there a better/systematic way to make sense from the error message/trace?

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

error most likely means that `cleanup() === undefined`, while Jest tries to call `afterEach` function like `fn.call()`, because functions are expected to have `call` method.

Make sure you're using latest Jest version and consider opening an issue in Jest repository regarding cryptic stack trace. It would be reasonable for the framework to validate `afterEach`, etc. arguments before running a suite to provide more meaningful feedback.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how one reaches the conclusion you have drawn above form the stacktrace. Please could you elaborate? The example above has been simplified. Imagine a big test case with several lines of code. How do I pinpoint/come close to the problem line?

Comment: This was a conclusion purely based on `afterEach(cleanup())` vs `afterEach(cleanup)` results. I agree that stack trace is not helpful at all in this case. The problem could be possibly tracked to this line if you were using a debugger.

Comment: Ok cool. Yeah, I'm new to this and thus trying to understand if I am missing a trick. This makes sense now that I know what the problem line is, but it took me a fair while to get to it.

Comment: It becomes a bit easier once you know what you're looking for. A similar problem that points to the cause could possibly be found by error message, although I've seen none. Also, TypeScript is definitely helpful at early detection of such issues.

Answer (score 0):

I believe when passing a function to afterEach without a defined anonymous function, you need to pass it without the calling parentheses.

```
afterEach(cleanup)
```

In terms of why the error is so cryptic, it is likely that the internals of Jest are expecting a function reference to be passed to `afterEach`. In this case, you're passing whatever the outcome of running `cleanup()` is, so it is unlikely to have a call property